# dynamic allocation : buffer vs memory stack

Tags: performance, visual-c++, memory-management, assembly

I'm going to allocate a new object without using any **`new`** operators. And I found two methods :

**The first one** is using an additional buffer (it needs to be kept track) :

```
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
char *pos = buffer;

Object *myObject; = (Object*)pos;
pos += OBJECT_SIZE;
```

**The second** one is using directly memory stack (esp) :

```
Object *myObject;
__asm sub esp, OBJECT_SIZE //make room for a variable
__asm mov dword ptr[myObject], esp
```

I don't see any errors, however what is different between them? And which method is better, faster and safer?

Comment: Any reason why you can't just do it the standard C++ way, e.g. Object myObject;  ?

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a common library function that does this for you: `alloca`. It usually acts like your second snippet of code, except most compilers can be actually intelligent about optimizing it.

The major downsides of the first one is that:

1. You only have a limited amount of memory.
2. You end up wasting however much memory you aren't using.

Comment: `alloca` is (relatively) common, but not standard.